# make a request from java application to a web server url

Tags: java, webserver, esp32

I made a web-server that runs on an esp32(LAN) and I have made it possible to send information to the esp itself from the servers url, (example : 192.168.1.39/?userInput=123), the number 123 is what I want to send from the application depends on the user's input (I compiled it to a packet of 8bits) so max number is 255, the server has an XML and some basic UI for viewing the information passed back and forth, I wanna be able to send the so called packet to the server and it passing it to the esp32 with almost no delay, I used google firebase before but it has way too much delay for it to be usable, I tried using a WebView and loading the URL with the number from the packet, I ran out of ideas on how to approach this would love some advice :)

I tried searching other questions here on the site, asked friends/teachers, watched a few tutorials and asked chatGPT for help but nothing was helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you just need to send the request (and maybe read out the response) or do you also need to display resulting HTML code?

Comment: I just need to send a request and not get anything back, just send the update to the server

Comment: All of my code is in my githib page : github.com/T3co/NPC_Mobile

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question it seems you are lost setting up server and client at the same time. Divide the tasks into chunks you can digest:

First, setup your ESP32 webserver. Follow a tutorial like https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/ and test it using a normal web browser. It can be used to run GET requests easily, and the amount of data you need to transfer that should definitely be enough. Alternatively you can use [curl](https://curl.se/) to send client requests.

Next, develop your java client to send the appropriate request. You can test the behaviour using any standard webserver and check the logs.

Finally put the ESP32 url into your client and see whether they work together.

Comment: I used the library WebServer.h for esp, the server works and I am able to communicate from its website and back but I cannot send the info from the app to the website, it says connection reset, probably due to large request amount that was being sent fom the webview

Comment: What webview are you talking about?

Comment: The one in android studio, thats where im building the app